# Loop over attribute table of selected layer

Tags: arcpy

Here's a stab at my first practical ArcPy script.

I want to grab a layer by name (rather than by layer order or by file path) in the current MXD, then loop over it's attributes (with a view to modifying them). However I don't know the syntax of connecting the desired layer to the attribute table

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
needle = "1km_Grid"
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
    if lyr.name == needle:
    # curObj = this layer # pseudo code!

columns = ["MID", "Shape"]

for row in curObj:
    print ("column 1 is: %s" % (row[0]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you get the lyr.name, use the [Update Cursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) to loop over the attributes and make changes as needed.

```
if lyr.name == needle:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lyr, columns) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            print "column 1 is: {}".format(row[0])
```

Comment: For the win how do I then update the attribute table? `arcpy.Buffer_analysis(columns)` doesn't work.

Comment: The buffer method buffers features not table attributes.  If you want to run the buffer method on the layer you do not need to use the cursor.  If you need to run the buffer on only certain features within the layer you will need to convert the layer to a feature layer and then make a selection on the layer/features then use the buffer method.  Note, that buffer method creates a new layer.

Comment: Ahh, my confusion I thought you needed to run than after updating a table.